# Not getting proper api resonse in flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart, jsonresponse

Getting the below issue when I pass the value in variable in json.encode not getting the excepted response, but I when pass the value without variable getting proper response I tried using map and different headers not able to get the exact issue.

1. Not working

   String getvalue = “response-value”;
   var _body = json.encode({"context": getvalue});

   var res = await http.post(link, headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   }, body: _body
   );
2. working

   var _body = json.encode({
   "responseValue”:
   "response-value"
   });

   var res = await http.post(link, headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   }, body: _body
   );

Comment: `getvalue` should probably be `"${getvalue}"`.

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of **_body** in both the cases to see if there is a difference?

Comment: @beria yes i tried printing both of the response but there was no difference

Comment: @DarShan i will try it

Comment: @DarShan I tried using "${getvalue}" but not solved. Will dio plugin helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved, there was issue an issue in the backend api which got solved know.